# Find keyframes of keyed uv-coordinates from animall plugin in blender

Tags: key, extract, blender, frames

I'm writing a script for extracting meshes and its attributes on a keyframe basis. I obtain the usual matrix transformations by iterating over `animation_data` of each object to access:

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.animation_data.action.fcurves.keyframe_points.co
```

Keyframes of blend shapes are stored somewhere else so that I obtain the keyframes by iterating over `animation_data` of the `shape_keys`:

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.data.shape_keys.animation_data.action.fcurves.keyframe_points.co
```

Now I animated the uv-coordinates with the animall-plugin in blender and want to extract them in the same way I do it for the other two cases already. I can see the keyframes in the Graph Editor and can access uv-coordinates by this exemplary call:

```
bpy.data.meshes["Cube"].uv_layers["UVMap"].data[3].uv[1]
```

My questions are now: 
- Where can I find the corresponding `animation_data` or `fcurves` block?
- If there is no corresponding `animation_data`, how do I get access to these keyframes?

Below you can find a screenshot of my debugging example. I want to get the keyframes 1 and 57.

[Link to Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38QcC.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it: I need to iterate over `bpy.data.meshes["name of meshobject"].animation_data`

Comment: Or if you want to go from the object it's `bpy.data.objects['Cube'].data.animation_data.action.fcurves`